Having trouble with my django project in regards to my one to one field in models, I believe the issue stems from my views.py file
So, before the one to one field being added I had no issues pulling the data from the html files but with the addition of the one to one field  I can no longer pull data from the html it gives me an error saying "The view main.views.registration didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead." I've tried to make changes in my views.py file to no longer have that issue not sure what is going wrong.
Below is some snippets of my code in regards to my models.py file for Students and Survey and then in views.py file in regards to my registration and survey.
Code Snippet of my views.py
class Student(models.Model):
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(default='example@example.com')
    phone_num = models.CharField(max_length=15, default='xxx-xxx-xxxx')
    dob = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='DD-MM-YYYY')
    student_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='xxxxxxx')
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
        ('O', 'Other')
    )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default='Other')
    Str_add = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='Street Name')
    Str_add = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Brownsville')
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='785xx')
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Texas')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.student_id + " " + self.fname
    
class Survey(models.Model):
    student = models.OneToOneField(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    QUESTION1_CHOICES = (
        ('E', 'Elementary'),
        ('J', 'Jr. High School/Middle School'),
        ('H', 'High School'),
        ('S', 'Some College'),
        ('C', 'College Degree'),
        ('U', 'Unknown')
    )
    question1 = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=QUESTION1_CHOICES)
    QUESTION2_CHOICES = (
        ('Y', 'Yes'),
        ('N', 'No')
    )
    question2 = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=QUESTION2_CHOICES)
    QUESTION3_CHOICES = (
        ('Y', 'Yes'),
        ('N', 'No')
    )
    question3 = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=QUESTION3_CHOICES)
    QUESTION4_CHOICES = (
        ('Y', 'Yes'),
        ('N', 'No')
    )
    question4 = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=QUESTION4_CHOICES)
    GPA = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    QUESTION6_CHOICES = (
        ('C', 'Plan on going to college'),
        ('N', 'Not going to college'),
        ('M', 'Plan to enroll in military'),
        ('W', 'Plan to work'),
        ('O', 'Other')
    )
    question6 = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=QUESTION6_CHOICES)
    first_choice = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    second_choice = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    QUESTION9_CHOICES = (
        ('C', 'Certificate'),
        ('A', 'Associate'),
        ('B', 'Bachelors'),
        ('M', 'Military'),
        ('O', 'Other')
    )
    question9 = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=QUESTION9_CHOICES)
    QUESTION10_CHOICES = (
        ('Y', 'Yes'),
        ('N', 'No')
    )
    question10 = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=QUESTION10_CHOICES)
    QUESTION11_CHOICES = (
        ('P', 'Pending'),
        ('A', 'Accepted')
    )
    question11 = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=QUESTION11_CHOICES)
    QUESTION12_CHOICES = (
        ('N', 'Not Testing'),
        ('R', 'Registered'),
        ('T', 'Tested')
    )
    question12 = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=QUESTION12_CHOICES)
    QUESTION13_CHOICES = (
        ('S', 'SAT'),
        ('A', 'ACT'),
        ('N', 'N/A')
    )
    question13 = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=QUESTION13_CHOICES)
    test_date = models.DateField()
    QUESTION15_CHOICES = (
        ('S', 'Sent'),
        ('P', 'Pending')
    )
    question15 = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=QUESTION15_CHOICES)
    QUESTION16_CHOICES = (
        ('S', 'Sent'),
        ('P', 'Pending')
    )
    question16 = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=QUESTION16_CHOICES)
    QUESTION17_CHOICES = (
        ('T', 'Tested-Pass'),
        ('F', 'Tested-Fail'),
        ('P', 'Pending')
    )
    question17 = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=QUESTION17_CHOICES)
    QUESTION18_CHOICES = (
        ('Y', 'Yes'),
        ('N', 'No')
    )
    question18 = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=QUESTION18_CHOICES)
    QUESTION19_CHOICES = (
        ('F', 'FAFSA'),
        ('T', 'TAFSA'),
        ('O', 'Other')
    )
    question19 = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=QUESTION19_CHOICES)
    QUESTION20_CHOICES = (
        ('Y', 'Yes'),
        ('N', 'No')
    )
    question20 = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=QUESTION20_CHOICES)
    appliedforAid = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Survey for {self.student.fname}"


Image is a screenshot snipped from my admins page where it shows my survey model where the one to one field does work
I've tried several different changes in my views.py file the photo above was my most current to date change. Previously I had done some minor changes in regards to that code I've changed some stuff removes some code in my return redirect('survey', student_id=student_id) changed some things there tried render in out of both nothing has really worked tried to watch youtube videos in regards to my problem but it seems everybody has a different setup where the in models it has a user being imported like "from django.contrib.auth.models import User" in my models I have is from django.db import models and then made a class for each model for my database.
